# Is there a better way of passing Props through react-router in 2016

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React-Router in the following way to pass props.

```
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/about' component={About} propName="test prop" />
    </Router>)
```

Props are then accessible via a nested array of props as:

```
this.props.routes[2]
```

This does work however it's somewhat painful and I can see this becoming untenable as the size of the app increases. Is there a better way to use props with React-Router?

Thanks!

Comment: `<Route>` components are only used for configuration, not rendering. Why are you trying to attach props to a specific route?

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's a good point, previously using flowRouter I used this pattern to pass route specific parameters, maybe this is a completely incorrect paradigm though... /Imofftoreadthedocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul mentions above, react-router is not used for rendering components, so the question doesn't really make sense.